# Strange behaviour of seekp(...) in C++

Tags: c++, output

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream in("test.txt");
    in.seekp(10);

    string testStr;
    in >> testStr;
    cout << testStr;

    return 0;
}
```

The file "test.txt" contain the following text:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

When I compile this code at Windows and run I get the output = 5, when I compile this code at Linux Mint 17 and run I get output = 6.

Why?

Comment: To make your code safe for any whitespace or length of integers in the file, you will need to parse and discard X numbers until you get to the one you want. If you use a binary data file with no whitespace and fixed-length representation of numbers, then you could use seek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess, but in Windows editors tend to write newlines as two characters: `\n\r`, while in linux it's only `\n`. So you could see your file in Windows as:

```
1\n\r
2\n\r
3\n\r
4\n\r
5\n\r
```

And in Linux

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
4\n
5\n
6\n
```

So in Windows moving the seeker at 10 would put it on the `\n` after 4, thus extracting 5 next. In Linux the seeker would go on 6, thus extracting it. To test if my guess is correct try copying the Windows file to Linux and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I forgot about this peculiar property.

Answer (score 1):

The newline (\n) for linux and carriage return (\r)+line feed (\f) for windows are getting counted and included when you specify 10 bytes.
On Windows, try this:

```
in.seekp(10*3);
```

Similarly, in Linux,

```
in.seekp(10*2);
```

But, instead if you read entire line for 10 times and discard the input that would be better, in case you have more than one char per line

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition and is therefore superfluous.

Comment: For double byte locale, like japanese or chinese character set sizeof(char) may not be 1

Comment: No, `sizeof(char)` is ALWAYS 1, defined in the standard. It may not always be 8 bits.

Comment: Even though it's superfluous, I don't object to its use to clarify the meaning of the magic number in the code.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, that you wrote, and I get result, that you described. It is a good illustration of a comment above.